# IOS : How can I override a delegate directly in the parameters of a method?

Tags: ios, swift, overriding

In java, it is possible to override an object directly in the parameters of a method :

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(@NonNull View view, @NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

I would like to do the same thing with Swift, for example :

```
let joinSocket: GCDAsyncSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {

    }
    
    func sendValue(str: String) {

    }
    
    func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {

    }
    
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {

    }
    
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didWriteDataWithTag tag: Int) {

    }
}, delegateQueue: .main)
```

However the code above returns this error :

> 'GCDAsyncSocketDelegate' cannot be constructed because it has no
> accessible initializers

How can I override a delegate directly in the parameters of a method with swift 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GCDAsyncSocketDelegate` is a protocol. You need to provide an implementation of said protocol and only then you can construct it like you want to.

```
class DefaultGCDAsyncSocketDelegate: GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {

    }
    
    func sendValue(str: String) {

    }
    
    func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {

    }
    
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {

    }
    
    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didWriteDataWithTag tag: Int) {

    }
}

let joinSocket: GCDAsyncSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: DefaultGCDAsyncSocketDelegate(), delegateQueue: .main)
```